# Install tkinter on ironpython

Tags: python, windows, module, tkinter, ironpython

I downloaded the ironpython 2.7.5 binaries from the site, and I require access to tkinter, and turtle graphics. These are not included by default in the binaries. I'm in an extremely limited enviroment, because I'm at school. All my files are stored on a Z: drive, on an external server that is accessed by each computer in the school. Therefore, I can't access the C: drive. So I can't use MSI files. I can, however, run zip files, which is how I have both Blender 2.79 and Ironpython on it. My problem is TKINTER! I need it, and I don't know how to get it. I don't even know where Ironpython reads modules from! And after that I need to know where to get tkinter from.

Comment: I don't think Tkinter will work with iron python.

Comment: That's a shame. Are you sure?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does, tkinter has a whole section in the documentation. But that doesn't say stuff about installation

Comment: NVM, it doesn't. IDK why it's in the iron python docs

Comment: @LukeTaylor If you've found the documentation saying it doesn't work in IronPython, could you please post link as an answer? I just spend half an hour trying to get it to work.

Comment: No, but it's my understanding that iron python only works with modules written in pure-python or written in .net (I could be wrong)

Comment: There is a way which is explained here, but unfortunately the download page is currently down: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/cpython_extensions.shtml